# How to create an appointment in outlook with vb?

Tags: vb.net, outlook

I have a winforms application and I'm trying to create a method that will create a new Outlook appointment. 
I am using the following code, but Mark an error in the part of the creation of the object `newAppointment`.

```
Private Sub AddAppointment()
    Dim newAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem = Me.Application.CreateItem _
         (Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
    Try
        With newAppointment
            .Start = Date.Now.AddHours(2)
            .End = Date.Now.AddHours(3)
            .Location = "ConferenceRoom #2345"
            .Body = _
                "We will discuss progress on the group project."
            .Subject = "Group Project"
            .AllDayEvent = False
            .Recipients.Add("Roger Harui")
            Dim sentTo As Outlook.Recipients = .Recipients
            Dim sentInvite As Outlook.Recipient
            sentInvite = sentTo.Add("Holly Holt")
            sentInvite.Type = Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired
            sentInvite = sentTo.Add("David Junca")
            sentInvite.Type = Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olOptional
            sentTo.ResolveAll()
            .Save()
            .Display(True)
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("The following error occurred: " & _
            ex.Message)
    End Tryenter code here
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Access to an `Outlook Application` object is required, because your own `Application` has no suitable `CreateItem` method:

Something along these lines:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop

....

Private Sub AddAppointment()
    '--- Check if Outlook is already up and running
    If Process.GetProcessesByName("outlook").Count > 0 Then
        '--- all ready ---
    Else
        '--- start Outlook ---
        Process.Start("outlook")
        '--- more elaborate wait might be a good idea here ---
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500)
    End If

    '--- initialize required Application object ---
    '--- assuming it is not available as variable already ---
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
    objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

    Dim newAppointment As Outlook.AppointmentItem =
        objOutlook.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
    Try
        With newAppointment
            .Start = Date.Now.AddHours(2)
            .End = Date.Now.AddHours(3)
            .Location = "ConferenceRoom #2345"
            .Body = "We will discuss progress on the group project."
            .Subject = "Group Project"
            .AllDayEvent = False
            .Recipients.Add("Roger Harui")
            Dim sentTo As Outlook.Recipients = .Recipients
            Dim sentInvite As Outlook.Recipient
            sentInvite = sentTo.Add("Holly Holt")
            sentInvite.Type = Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired
            sentInvite = sentTo.Add("David Junca")
            sentInvite.Type = Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olOptional
            sentTo.ResolveAll()
            .Save()
            .Display(True)
        End With
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("The following error occurred: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it worked out that way, you just saved me

Answer (score 0):

This may be a little from what you were initially thinking of, but I think it will help you get started in the right direction.

If you want to create an appointment in Outlook, using Excel, run the script below (in Excel).

```
Private Sub Add_Appointments_To_Outlook_Calendar()

    'Include Microsoft Outlook nn.nn Object Library from Tools -> References
    Dim oAppt As AppointmentItem
    Dim Remind_Time As Double

    i = 2
    Subj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)

    'Loop through entire list of Reminders to be added
    While Subj <> ""
        Set oAppt = Outlook.Application.CreateItem(olAppointmentItem)

        oAppt.Subject = Subj
        oAppt.Location = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2)
        oAppt.Start = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3)
        Remind_Time = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4) * 1 * 60
        oAppt.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Remind_Time
        oAppt.AllDayEvent = True
        oAppt.Save

        i = i + 1
        Subj = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1)
    Wend
    MsgBox "Reminder(s) Added To Outlook Calendar"

End Sub
```

' The code comes from this link:
 http://officetricks.com/add-appointment-to-outlook-calendar-through-excel-macro-vba/

Here is a screen of what the setup should look like.

[image]